# How to pipe foreach output to export-csv

Tags: powershell

The code below outputs the following.

TYPE System.String
Length
100

How can I get it to actually output the content of the strings?

```
$fileIn | % { $array = $_.split(" ")
    if ($array[0] -eq "User") {
        $name = $array[1]+"."+$array[2]
        $remaining = ""
        for ($i = 3; $i -ne $array.length; $i++) {$remaining+=$array[$i]+" "}
        Get-ADUser $name -properties description, company | % { $name + " - " + 
            $remaining + " - " + $_.description + " - " + 
            $_.company | Export-CSV $output}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Export-CSV` is for exporting objects with properties to csv. You're trying to export a single string, which only includes a value and a `Length` property.

Also, `-` is not a valid delimiter in csv(at least not in .NET). The type information can be removed with a `-NoTypeInformation`-switch. Try this:

```
$fileIn | % { $array = $_.split(" ")
    if ($array[0] -eq "User") {
        $name = $array[1]+"."+$array[2]
        $remaining = ""
        for ($i = 3; $i -ne $array.length; $i++) {$remaining+=$array[$i]+" "}

        Get-ADUser $name -properties description, company | % { 
            New-Object psobject -Property @{
                "Name" = $name
                "Remaining" = $remaining
                "Description" = $_.Description
                "Company" = $_.Company
            }
        }
    }
} | Select-Object Name, Remaining, Description, Company | 
Export-CSV $output -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
```

I tried to understand what you where trying to do here. To give you a summary of the changes:

- I'm creating an object containing the information you want to export, for every row in your `$filein`
- I'm setting the order of the properties with `select-object` AFTER an object for every line in `$filein` has been created
- I'm exporting the array of objects to a csv-file with delimiter `;` (just to show how you specify it), and without the type-information at the start. If you use `export-csv` inside the foreach loop, it would overwrite the file every time and you'd just have one row + header-row in the end. In PS3.0 you could have done it inside the loop, using `-Append` switch.

**EDIT** If you really need the string format, you need to use something else then `Export-CSV`, ex. `Out-File` with `-Append` switch. Ex:

```
$fileIn | % { $array = $_.split(" ")
    if ($array[0] -eq "User") {
        $name = $array[1]+"."+$array[2]
        $remaining = ""
        for ($i = 3; $i -ne $array.length; $i++) {$remaining+=$array[$i]+" "}
        Get-ADUser $name -properties description, company | % { 
            "$name - $remaining - $($_.description) - $($_.company)" | Out-File -Append $output
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer!